# How to run hasura console on a different port when using docker

Tags: hasura

I am writing this question because I couldn't find a way to change the default Hasura console port when using Hasura docker image.

The page I'm referring [is this](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/hasura-cli/hasura_console.html)

[image]

There is no variable defined to change the Hasura default console port in the above page.

The reason I'm requesting this feature is to separate query histories of my two hasura projects. If I could manage to run these two consoles on two different ports I will be able to save the query/mutation history seperately.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Hasura image previously, but I have used docker a lot to run MySQL instances etc. What I typically do depends on whether or not I am using `docker-compose` or just plain `docker run`.

If using docker compose you can specify a port mapping for each container, e.g. map `9695` -> `9005` would look like so:

```
    hasura:
        image: hasura
        ports:
            - 9005:9695
```

or if using `docker run` following [these docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) e.g.
`docker run --expose 9695:9005 hasura ...`

Comment: setting the port will change the hasura api endpoint, not the hasura console.  and also I'm using network-mode host. so that I will not be able to use port forwarding like that

Answer (score 0):

Hasura's Dockerfile has `graphql-engine serve` as its `CMD`. You can override this default command by your own command and pass `--server-port` or any config to `serve`, as per the [reference page](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/deployment/graphql-engine-flags/reference.html).

> setting the port will change the hasura api endpoint, not the hasura console

That's not entirely true. If `HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true` Hasura will serve the console on the `/console` route of the server API endpoint. However, for production, [it's recommended](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/deployment/production-checklist.html#disable-console) to disable the console and run Hasura CLI locally, connected to the production instance.

Comment: How do you use the hasura CLI to connect to production?